# After woocommerce/wordpress registration

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I want to fire function after user finish his registration on my site.

I searched for next hook, but didn't found:

```
woocommerce_after_customer_register_form
```

I found only this:

```
woocommerce_after_checkout_registration_form
```

That's not help me, because i search for after register form on the site, and not after the checkout.

What is the trick i need to use to fire function after user registered ?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

WordPress core handles user registration and runs the [`user_register`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/user_register) hook right after a user is registered.

Taking from the codex an example would be:

```
add_action( 'user_register', 'myplugin_registration_save', 10, 1 );

function myplugin_registration_save( $user_id ) {

    if ( isset( $_POST['first_name'] ) )
        update_user_meta($user_id, 'first_name', $_POST['first_name']);

}
```

Comment: I have used this very useful answer for [**one of my answers**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37879112/woocommerce-filling-the-first-and-last-name-fields-in-the-user-profile-bug), thanks :)

Comment: Just to add to this answer, at least for any future searchers looking for WooCommerce specific answers. The POST values for first name and last name are $_POST['sr_firstname']; $_POST['sr_lastname']; I used helgatheviking's answer to create a function that sends a custom admin email on new WooCommerce account sign-ups. Gist is here: https://gist.github.com/tnog/d4429308de47d25c814cb5bb82b38c56

Comment: When using 'user_register' hook the user_meta data is not available.