# Make User Email Lowercase on Wordpress User Registration

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I am having some issues with user emails being saved to the database upon registration with capital letters. I know how to update the email field in SQL to `LOWER` all the values. However, it would be nice to catch this upon registration. I use Woocommerce to create accounts, and after some reading it seems that Woo uses the standard Wordpress `user_register` hook to create accounts ([got that from this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28135954/after-woocommerce-wordpress-registration)).

**Example**: user registers with `Myemail@email.com`. I need this to save to their account and the user table as `myemail@email.com`. I tried to scrape together the following plugin to handle this, but after testing on my site it still results in `Myemail@email.com` upon registration.

*Note*: I have tried CSS tricks like `style="text-transform:lowercase;"` but these only mask the style of the input and don't affect the syntax of the email as it's saved to the database.

```
/* Update User Email on Register Account - LOWER CASE
------------------------------------------------------------------ */
add_action( 'user_register', 'lower_email_register_form', 10, 1 ); 

function lower_email_register_form( $user_id ) { 

    if ( isset( $_POST['user_email'] ) )
        update_user_meta($user_id, 'user_email', strtolower( $_POST['user_email']) );

};
```

Comment: Not familiar with ther of these products, but you have to get your code run BEFORE the data gets stored to the database is there a `before_user_register` hook? Or something like that?

Comment: *Why* do you "need" to save it in lower case? Email addresses are case-insensitive by their nature, there should be no problem with allowing people to use capital letters if they want.

Comment: @GregSchmidt I have a plugin that a developer built for us that splits payment products among user by email. I have run into repeat issues that break the functions due to email case sensitivity. If the user splits a payment with another user name@email.com, but the user registered as Name@email.com, it will not function. Rather than working through the entire plugin to fix there, I want to just prevent it at the outset at registration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Took some direction from the comments and found a filter that happens before the data is stored. `pre_user_email` did the trick. Here's my updated plugin that makes user emails lowercase upon registration:

```
/* Filter User Email on Registration to Ensure Lower Case
------------------------------------------------------------------ */
function filter_pre_user_email( $raw_user_email ) { 
    
    $raw_user_email = strtolower($raw_user_email);
    
    return $raw_user_email; 
}; 
         
// add the filter 
add_filter( 'pre_user_email', 'filter_pre_user_email', 10, 1 );
```

I found [this visual guide](https://usersinsights.com/wordpress-user-registration-hooks-visualized/) to registration hooks helpful in identifying the right hook.